# Mockito: not throwing expected exception

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I need to test exception handling in the following piece of code:

```
@Component
public class RewardsOperation {

    public RewardsOperation(CustomerProfileService customerProfileService){
        this.customerProfileService = customerProfileService;
    }

    @Override
    public RestConsumerResponse<PointsFulfillResponseData> handle(RestConsumerRequest<PointsFulfillRequest> consumerRequest) {

        try {
            customerProfile = customerProfileService.getCustomerProfile(consumerRequest);
       } catch (RestConnectorException exp) {
       ...
      }
```

This is the test case I wrote:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class RewardsOperationTest {

    @Mock
    CustomerProfileService customerProfileService;

    RewardsOperation sut;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        restConsumerRequest = RestConsumerRequest.<PointsFulfillRequest>builder().request(PointsFulfillRequest.buildExample()).build();

        Notification notification = Notification.builder()
                .code("E_CBTCUST_PROFILE_2001")
                .build();
        restConnectorException = new RestConnectorException(notification, new Exception());
        sut = new RewardsOperation(customerProfileService);
    }

    @Test
    public void handleRestConnectorExceptionTest() throws IOException {
        // Given
        Mockito.when(customerProfileService.getCustomerProfile(restConsumerRequest)).thenThrow(restConnectorException);
        // THEN
        Assertions.assertThrows(RestConnectorException.class, ()-> sut.handle(restConsumerRequest));
    }
}
```

When I run the test, it showed that no excpetion was thrown

```
RewardsOperationTest > handleRestConnectorExceptionTest() FAILED
    org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: Expected com.bns.chassis.starter.rest.exceptions.RestConnectorException to be thrown, but nothing was thrown.
        ...
        at com.aab.api.points.fulfillment.operation.RewardsOperationTest.handleRestConnectorExceptionTest(RewardsOperationTest.java:26)
```

Anyone could help point out what I missed?

Answer (score 0):

As for me you need to mock service and then inject mocks to your class that you are testing.

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class RewardsOperationTest {

    @Mock
    private CustomerProfileService customerProfileService;

    @InjectMocks
    private RewardsOperation rewardsOperation;

    @Test
    public void handle_withRestConnectorException_shouldHandleException() throws RestConnectorException {
        RestConsumerRequest<PointsFulfillRequest> consumerRequest = mock(RestConsumerRequest.class);
        RestConnectorException restConnectorException = mock(RestConnectorException.class);
        when(customerProfileService.getCustomerProfile(consumerRequest)).thenThrow(restConnectorException);

        RestConsumerResponse<MortgPointsFulfillResponseData> response = rewardsOperation.handle(consumerRequest);

        Assertions.assertThrows(RestConnectorException.class, ()-> rewardsOperation.handle(restConsumerRequest));

    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't resolve the issue. still nothing was thrown.

Comment: ctrl+c and ctrl + v is evil, need to change sut with rewardsOperation